# Why do appengine logs show that my task's request takes much longer than appstats does?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, task-queue

I'm seeing pretty slow performance of tasks enqueued in the taskqueue - the task's requests are finishing in about 10+ seconds according to the logs, while the appstats show closer to 1 second.

For example, one request's entry in the logs:

> 0.1.0.2 - - [24/Feb/2014:16:01:38 -0800] "POST [URI] HTTP/1.1" 200 59 "[URL]" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)"
>   "[domain name]" ms=39422 cpu_ms=70 cpm_usd=0.002559 queue_name=[queue
>   name] task_name=[task name] pending_ms=9339 exit_code=101
>   app_engine_release=1.8.9 instance=[instance]

Here's the corresponding appstats times:

> real=1150ms api=0ms overhead=14ms

Why is there this large discrepancy between what appstats shows and what the logs show?

This is for an app written in python 2.7.

Comment: Do you have warmup requests enabled? My guess is not, and so you are seeing startup time, which is all the time spent prior to any of your code being run.  Add some logging in appengine_config.py and at the beginning  your main app handler and inside the handler.  Then you can see how long each phase takes. Time from start of request in the log and your first code emitted log message will be startup time.